# Lumens VC LC101 - Authorization error

Tags: c#, session

I'm currently making a web application to control a Lumens LC101. When I login to the device I get a session id, which I use to call commands, for authorization. But when I call a command - for example `keepalive` - and posted the session with it, Lumens gives me an authorization error code: -14.

This is how I post the session and call a command:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
// Create HttpWebRequest
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.103/api/keepalive");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

// Post json data
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
    streamWriter.Write("{\"session\":\"" + session + "\"}");
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

// Get response of HttpWebRequest
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
// Read stream from response
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
JObject jsonResult = JObject.Parse(result);
int code = Int32.Parse(jsonResult.GetValue("code").ToString());
// Return result
if (code >= 0) return result;
```

`int code` will be `-14` in this case, because authorization failed. But I'm using the same session id, which I got from the login.

How do I make sure it won't give me an authorization error code: -14?

**EDIT**

This is how it's described in the documentation:

[image: Documentation image]

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bgxndkyczcw3vw/CBoxSDK.pdf?dl=0) the documentation. Session is described in paragraph 1.2